# How to add point on OpenStreetMap through API?

Tags: api, addition, openstreetmap, point

I want to add points on OSM using API. Is it possible?
If it does, can you give me an example?

For example if i want to add this point

```
name: Musen & Elefanten
city: Gotham City
address: Vestergade 21
longitude: 12.5699
latitude: 55.6774
category: pub
```

i can add it using OSM website... how to do the same through API?

Answer (score 2):

You want to checkout the following links:

- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Automated_Edits
- [https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Create:*PUT*.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangeset.2Fcreate](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Create:_PUT_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangeset.2Fcreate)
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

BUT you need to understand that the OSM community is **very skeptical** about such kinds of imports! I highly recommend to [talk to local users](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact) BEFORE you run any bot and add your data! In worst case you will get blamed because you created dublicates, destroyed data, or imported outdated bulk data! Don't get me wrong, but this question might show that you are currently not in a good position to add 100s of fresh data, as you don't seem to already understand basics of the OSM project. Please take the time to learn more and ask others how you might proceed with your tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I don't want to do bulk import, i just want to make my users add their point in an easy way through a form, in which they just add LAT, LON and their details

Comment: Which doesn't solve the problem of dublicates nor the quality of entered data. It also might breake the chain of communication that is a must-have feature at OSM so mappers can talk to each others to avoid edit-wars :/

Comment: I see... so what's the difference with entering the same details on OSM website through Edit button?

Comment: The difference is that you will have an user account. So local people are able to contact and communicate with you if something is wrong or unclear about the information you added.

Comment: Don't misunderstand our arguments, but had some bad experiences with imports and even middleware that allows third party users to edit OSM. Took long time in most cases till the results were good and a benefit for everybody :-)

Comment: I have still not read the links to wiki posted above because i'm on phone, but i ask this: isn't the adding through API connected to an OSM user? If it is so local people  are able to contact and communicate with me if something is wrong... Am i right?

Comment: stop crossposting and continue at help.osm.org!

Comment: They are able to communicate with you but not with your users. And this is bad.